# HTML and JAVASCRIPT Editor in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angularjs 1.5.8 application created using Jhipster.

For my website I want to make a HTML and JAVASCRIPT editor. Need to allow user to write HTML Code but JAVASCRIPT also.

Using this library I know I can achieve the follow.

https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile

1: Bind HTML Code.
2: Bind Angular code if present in HTML

Eg: `<h1>{{$scope.test}}</h1>`

Would render correct value in the scope.

But what about something like this in the html

```
<script>
console.log($scope);
</script>
```

I get a $scope not defined error, somehow the $scope value is not available in the script tag.

If anyone curious that why I need to do this because we want to provide users of the application to create there own Angularjs Forms.

Comment: $scope is private constructor in Angular's code so you can't use it in script tag, and why you want to use it there? User can create forms dynamically

Comment: I am not sure who added -1 to the question, if people cant understand it they can still ask before adding -1

@MountainKing thank you for commenting.

I actually found an answer and I will post it soon to help others if they face such an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using ng-include, here is the example source.

I wanted to do two things.

**1:** Make ng-include work from a scope variable which will contain html and javascript.

**2:** In the included string if I have a script tag I wanted it to render correct in the ng-include.

To achieve the **#1** I did the following.

Used $templateCache service.

Sample code.

```
$templateCache.put('template-form', vm.html + vm.script);
```

For point #2

I made sure the script tag is structured in the following way.

```
<script>
(function() {
    'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp').controllerProvider.register('AppTemplateController',AppTemplateController);
  AppTemplateController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function AppTemplateController($scope){
    // WRITE YOUR CODE IN THIS CONTROLLER
    // YOU CAN WRITE YOUR VARIABLES/FUNCTIONS HERE.
    // MAKE SURE TO CALL THE method "vm.submitForm", to submit your form and pass the form object.
  };

})();
</script>
```

This way you can inject a controller.

My requirement was very very specific to my projecct, I am not sure if others who did not face this issue even would understand what I am talking about. But for those who do face it,  I hope you it helpful